# Workday SOAP API and multilingual deployments

Tags: multilingual, workday-api

Looking at Workday's public SOAP API (https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/index.html) The WSDL does not seem to indicate any way to pass in the locale of the data I wanted -- if Workday is configured to be multilingual, how do I specify which locale I need the data to be when using the API?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the multilingual support is for display in Workday. I can't find any mention of it within the APIs.

> Workday provides 3 levels of international localization support:
>
> - Locales enable you to control **the display** of multinational date, time, and number formats.
> - Languages enable you to control the display of text **in Workday**.
> - Localized fields enable you to track certain types of information depending on the country.